# poco 64 bit Foundation static lib -> unresolved Symbol "GetAdaptersInfo"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, 64-bit, poco, foundation

I am using poco. I just updated to version 1.8.1-all and compiled PocoFoundation in 64 bit mode (debug static md, release static md) with Visual Studio 2017.

**My Setting**: Windows 10 64 bit machine. Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

When binding it into my c++ project, i get a link-error:

**Unresolved external Symbol : "GetAdaptersInfo"**

I noticed, it's used wihin "Environment_WIN32.cpp" and it's actually defined in

*c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\IPHlpApi.h*

Do you know, how to fix that?

This only occurrs in 64 bit. I set the CompilerVersion to SDK 8.1 for build tools 141 in my Visual Studio 2017-Project

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio, in your solution's property pages, add iphlpapi.lib to the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies list and you should be good.